# How to fix nsfw error for stable diffusion?

Tags: python, huggingface

I always get the "Potential NSFW content was detected in one or more images. A black image will be returned instead. Try again with a different prompt and/or seed." error when using stable diffusion, even with the code that was given on huggingface:

```
import torch
from torch import autocast
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

model_id = "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4"
device = "cuda"
token = 'MY TOKEN'


pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16, revision="fp16", use_auth_token=token)
pipe = pipe.to(device)

prompt = "a photo of an astronaut riding a horse on mars"
with autocast("cuda"):
    image = pipe(prompt, guidance_scale=7.5).images[0]  
    
image.save("astronaut_rides_horse.png")
```

Comment: This did the trick for me https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/comments/wv2nw0/tutorial_how_to_remove_the_safety_filter_in_5/

Comment: I don't really want to disable the nsfw filter. I just asking if I messed up somewhere with the installation because I always get that error with any given prompt.

Answer (score 11):

They have a single variable to remove it `safety_checker`.

```py
StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    safety_checker = None,
)
```

However, depending on the pipelines you use, you can get a warning message if `safety_checker` is set to `None`, but `requires_safety_checker` is `True`.

From pipeline_stable_diffusion_inpaint_legacy.py

```py
if safety_checker is None and requires_safety_checker:
            logger.warning(f"...")
```

So you can do this:

```py
StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    safety_checker = None,
    requires_safety_checker = False
)
```

You can also change it later if necessary by doing this.

```py
pipeline.safety_checker = None
pipeline.requires_safety_checker = False
```

Answer (score 3):

This covers a bit of what the checker does: https://vickiboykis.com/2022/11/18/some-notes-on-the-stable-diffusion-safety-filter/

If you want to simply disable it, you can now set the `safety_checker` argument to `None` (no longer have to modify the source Python):

```py
StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    safety_checker = None,
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase, you can simply comment out the `run_safety_checker` function in `pipeline_stable_diffusion` `img2img` or `txt2img`. You can alter the function in this way.

```
def run_safety_checker(self, image, device, dtype):
    has_nsfw_concept = None
    return image, has_nsfw_concept
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable the NSFW check, try to articulate a different prompt which attempts to work around the problem.

Without having tried it, I would suggest to replace "riding" with something more explicitly safe, like "sitting on the back of".